# c++ boost serialization how to prevent crashes with improper files

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm using boosts serialization functions to serialize and save data to external files in my project and then to be able to read them in again.

The issue I'm having is that if a file is read in (in error) not in the correct format then the program crashes (perhaps expectedly).

How can I identify that the file is in the wrong format and interrupt the read in process before the program crashses?

EDIT:

I've tried a try catch construct in my read in function which looks like this

```
int read_binary(file_in_out* object){

    std::ifstream ifs((*object).file.c_str());

    try
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> (*object).content;


    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) 
    {
        std::cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. "  << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This catches an exception when the file is nothing to do with the structures that it is trying to read into it. However, when I use an out of date version it doesn't catch an exception and crashes on line 'ia >> (*object).content;' Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It should not crash. If it does, report a bug with the library developers.

It *should* raise exceptions though. So, you could try to catch archive exceptions:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html

```
    unregistered_class,     // attempt to serialize a pointer of an
                            // an unregistered class
    invalid_signature,      // first line of archive does not contain
                            // expected string
    unsupported_version,    // archive created with library version subsequent
                            // to this one
    pointer_conflict        // an attempt has been made to directly serialize
                            // an object after having already serialized the same
                            // object through a pointer.  Were this permitted, 
                            // it the archive load would result in the creation
                            // of extraneous object.
    incompatible_native_format, // attempt to read native binary format
                            // on incompatible platform
    array_size_too_short,   // array being loaded doesn't fit in array allocated
    stream_error            // i/o error on stream
    invalid_class_name,     // class name greater than the maximum permitted.
                            // most likely a corrupted archive or an attempt
                            // to insert virus via buffer overrun method.
    unregistered_cast       // base - derived relationship not registered with 
                            // void_cast_register
```

Also, catch `std::exception&` for e.g. `bad_alloc`, `range_error` etc.

Comment: It will crash inevitably if the file is in a binary format and the structured of the program do not match the structures, stored (unless versions are considered and precautions are taken).

Comment: @DieterLücking I think it's unfair to say "it will crash inevitably". Input sanitation exists and applies full well to binary input. It just requires attention to detail. I'm not sure about the built-in stuff, but I fully expect `std::bad_alloc` e.g. when wrongly reserving for a huge vector, and a nice Archive exception or `std::basic_istream::failure` if you reach unexpected end-of-file, missing delimiters, corrupted type codes...

Comment: @user3353819 can you give us a failing example and perhaps a file that triggers it? You might have found a bug/vulnerability worth reporting